# How create responsive design for inline-block game HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on simple Escape room game using HTML, CSS and JavaScript where every item in room is figure created by CSS. But I'm stuck trying to create responsive design. Whole room should  change size with different screens but still be inline. I tried grid and media queries but it's doesn't work with my figures. For now it’s just one size and a part of code in HTML and CSS looks like these:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #051217;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #071e26, #051217);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#door {
  width: 180px;
  height: 380px;
  display: fixed;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 2px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  background-color: #051217;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #071e26, #051217);
}

#handle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background-color: #051217;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #071e26, #051217);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 5%;
}

#keypad {
  width: 25px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 37%;
  left: 3%;
}

#input {
  width: 20px;
  height: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  top: 3%;
}

.keypad {
  width: 20px;
  height: 28px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 19%;
  left: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- Door -->
  <div id="door">
    <div id="handle"></div>
    <div id="keypad" onmouseover="keypadMouseOver()" onmouseout="keypadMouseOut()">
      <img class="keypad" src="static/images/keypad.png">
      <div id="input"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `display: fixed;` is a wrong property! Here is all about CSS display property https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: your topic question has nothing to do with `inline` as such I removed the tag. Also you not use any `inline-blocks` anyways. I highly recommend you to reconsider you approach and go with SVG-elements. They will scale perfectly. The first issue why your approach will enever be responsive is the use of position: fixed; as well as fixed pixel values instead of responsive values liek `%` or `vh/vw`